# Showing all images from a folder on main domain on a page on a subdomain

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, subdomain, directory

I am currently doing a translated version of a website on a subdomain test.exemple.com, I have to create pages that show images from folders in the main domain directory, on the sub domain page.

IE the images in exemple.com/images/cool/ have to be displayed on a page such as  test.exemple.com/wiki/cool.php that would list out all the images in the folder.

Here is the code that I use on the main domain to echo all the images.

```
$lower_name = strtolower($name);
$dirname =  "../images/".$lower_name."/public/";
$images = glob($dirname."*");
$i=0;
foreach($images as $image){
                $image = str_replace('../',"http://www.exemple.com/", $image);
                $userGallery[$i]=$image;
                $i=$i+1;
}
```

Now all this works fine on the main domain but on the subdomain the glob() returns a bool of false. Is there any way to fix this or another method that could be used here?

Comment: is the document root of the subdomain and the main domain the same ?

Comment: They are located on a private server with the main one in a file and the subdomain in another file on the same root

Comment: you didn't get my question , please read this http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-a-document-root-folder and make sure they point to the same root document

Comment: Sorry, the document root is not the same, they are in two different files /site1 and /site2

Comment: so change $dirname accordingly to match the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use realpath() function to get the canonicalized route to your image? something like:

```
$dirname = realpath("//example.com/images/".$lower_name."/public/");
```

When you use ../ it still looking within the root of text.example.com but not into example.com

Comment: When I use this I get all the files of the current directory of the subdomain for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to get the images this way so I set up an api on the main domain  and got the images through curl with php.